# Prove $x+y+z$ divides $x^2+y^2+z^2$ where x,y,z are consecutive terms in a geometric series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

The natural numbers $x,y,z$ are consecutive terms in a geometric series. Proves that $x+y+z$ divides $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

$x = ar\\
y = ar^2 = xr\\
z = ar^3 = xr^2$

So..

$\begin{align}
x + y + z & = x + xr + xr^2 \\
 & = x(1+r+r^2)\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 & = x^2 + x^2r^2 + x^2r^4\\
& = x^2(1+r^2+r^4)\end{align}$

I can see that x is a factor for both but I've no idea where to go from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remark that $1+r^2+r^4=(1+r+r^2)(1-r+r^2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, that solved it! How did you spot this so easily? I've just started university mathematics and I'm trying to get better at factorising because often I fail to spot them. Do you have any tips? I can spot easily $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$ but fail at anything more complex.

Comment: You're welcome! It's something you learn by experience. One way to notice this is that $1+r+r^2=(r-\omega)(r-\omega^2)$, where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ is a non-real solution to $\omega^3=1$. You can check that $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are both roots of $1+r^2+r^4$, which means that $1+r+r^2$ must be a factor of $1+r^2+r^4$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to observe that 
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+xz+yz)$$ 
and
$$xy+xz+yz=x^2r(1+r+r^2)$$

Comment: Thanks! I was working with $(x+y+z)^2$ from the start but I didn't spot that $xy+xz+yz = x^2r(1+r+r^2)$

Answer (score 0):

WLOG let $x=\frac 1r, y=1, z=r$. 
Then  $x+y+z=r+1+\frac 1r$.
Consider 
$$\left(\frac 1r+r+1\right)\left(\frac 1r+r-1\right)=\left(\frac 1r+r\right)^2-1^2\\
=\left(\frac 1{r^2}+2+r^2\right)-1\\
=\frac 1{r^2}+1+r^2\\
\Rightarrow \quad (x+y+z)(x-y+z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$$